# Supplement in finite groups

Tags: finite-groups, solvable-groups

Let $G$ be a finite non-Abelian group. Is it true that `` there exists a proper solvable subgroup  $A$ and a proper subgroup $B$ of $G$ such that $G=AB$?"

Comment: Nope: Consider $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$, where $p$ is prime. This group only has one proper subgroup, i.e., $\{1\}$, which obviously doesn't satisfy your criteria.

Comment: Thanks. That is true i missed to write the assumption $G$ is a non-abelian group

Comment: [Apparently the answer is yes.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/208810/is-there-a-big-solvable-subgroup-in-every-finite-group) In fact, you can require both $A, B$ to be solvable.

Comment: @MeesdeVries Is it obvious that the answer here follows from the MO question? Here the product is considered, while there the subgroup generated by them, which might be a lot larger.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I understand "$AB$" to mean "the subgroup generated by $A$ and $B$".

Comment: @MeesdeVries I think OP is using Minkowski notation.

Comment: @RushabhMehta What is Minkowski notation?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition

Comment: @RushabhMehta Not sure why you would call that Minkowski notation in this context. It is just the way one defines the product of subgroups in group theory.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft My professor called it Minkowski notation when I learned it. I apologize if that's not appropriate terminology.